# Android: how create button for every file in a folder

Tags: android, button, dynamic, view, directory

I'm doing an Android app that read files in a folder in sdcard. 
The files in this folder increase as I execute another operation.
This is my code that shows list of my files:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_activity);


            File storage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File file = new File(storage,"/myfolder/");
             //  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            if (file.exists() && file.isDirectory()) {
                for (String s : file.list()) {
                    sb.append(s + " ");
                }
            }
            MainActivity.this.setFileListString(sb.toString());

        }

protected void setFileListString(String string) {
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    text.setText(sb);

}
```

I want next to each file there is a button, this button must then create 
every time new files are created in the folder. 
How can I do? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using ListView with a adapter class which will create the listitem and button in front of your item. here is a small tutorial for the same :http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html